# What return common binary reading methods on the end of stream?

Tags: c#, stream, binary, byte

I have a small question. What return common binary reading methods on the end of stream? For example I have `Stream.ReadByte()` which returns single unsigned byte. What happens when I'm on the end of stream? And is there any difference when I'm using this method with NetworkStream? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation for the base class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.readbyte.aspx):

> **Return Value**
>
> Type: System.Int32
> The unsigned byte cast to an Int32, or -1 if at the end of the stream.

So, the method reads an int and casts it to a wider type, in order to be able to return additional -1 value at the end of the stream.

Both [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0bs3w9t.aspx) and [`NetworkStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx) are derived from [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx). This means that no difference in the logic is needed.

Comment: So what will be it? Exception, or -1?

Comment: @user: if we are talking about the same classes (see links in my answer), -1.

Comment: Yes, we are, but look on post which is down.

Comment: @user: do you mean the other answer? I think I've provided links to MSDN. MSDN is _the_ ultimate information source.

Comment: yes, but that links don't tell me if it will throw exception, or not. I hope that they'll not. I'm testing it.

Comment: @user: the links say that the function `ReadByte` will return -1 in case the stream is ended. Now, is it possible to return a value _and_ throw an exception at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the stream with a BinaryReder to have the same behavior for various stream types.
The reader will throw an exception when you read over the end.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.endofstreamexception(v=vs.80).aspx

**Exception or -1?**

it depends on how you read the stream

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("c:\\smple.bin", FileMode.Open))
{
    ...
    stream.ReadByte(); // will return -1 when reading over the end
}
```

but when you do it like this:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("c:\\smple.bin", FileMode.Open))
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
{
    ... 
    reader.ReadByte(); // will throw an exception
}
```

Comment: So what will be it? Exception, or -1?